# What is the difference between State, Activity and Action in Windows Workflow

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4

I am working on a project where `Windows Workflow 4` is used. I find it really difficult to make a clear difference/distinction between three of the basic concepts - `Action`, `Activity` and `State`. Because I know that here, questions that are not backed with previous research and effort to solve it by yourself I'll just post two of the articles which I think to read again because I feel I didn't understood them entirely :

[A Developer's Introduction to Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) in .NET 4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx)

[State Machines In Windows Workflow (OdeToCode)](http://odetocode.com/articles/460.aspx)

I've started to form some sort of understanding based on the read information but I feel I'm going the wrong way. Can someone use the `NumberGuessingGame` or some other simple `WF4` example and explain how to identify those three parts of the workflow and what are the basic criterias that make action an action, activity an activity and state a state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a graphical representation of a workflow: There are **Boxes** and **Lines** (or arrows) between between them.

Usually your system "stays" in one of the boxes until a "transition" (along one of the lines) moves it to another box.

Now an **Activity** is one of these Boxes (or a subset of several Boxes).

**Action** is sometimes used as a synonym of Activity, somtimes it is used for an event within the workflow framework and sometimes it means the `Action<T>` class of the underlying programming language.

Finally a **State** is just an "Activity" in the "State Machine" style of workflows. They use a different word for the same thing, because in the context of State Machines it is more convinient (less confusing) to talk about "States" than "Activities".